# How to use css media queries in svg based on screen not img size?

Tags: css, svg, media-queries

I have an svg for a cart icon and am able to style it with css.  I would like to change the color of the cart based on window size. The problem is `@media` reads the size of the image to test the media query rather than the window.

```
<defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
            #Mobile {
                fill: #fff;
            }
        }
    </style>
</defs>
```

The size of the image is 40 x 40px. Since the size of the image is set to remain constant the media query never becomes active.  Is there a way to make this bypass image size and read screen width like a normal media query?

I'm calling the svg in my html like this:

```
<object id="cartIcon" type="image/svg+xml" data="Assets/icon-shopping-cart.svg"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would apply the style via JS and use `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` to do the detection.

```
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

if ( width === 456 || height === 123) {
  var element = document.getElementById("Mobile");
  element.style.fill = "white"; 
}
```

Comment: this is a nice alternative, but are you saying it is not possible for the media query to read screen size in the svg?

Comment: Well, `min-width` and `max-width` are traditionally how you do window size detection with media queries in CSS. If those aren't precise enough, you probably have to lean on JS. There might be another way in CSS though, see if you get a better answer.